# VBA -- Using a Userbox checkbox as show below, how do I set the value of a variable using a checkbox and then use that variable in a Module?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

So currently, I have the following in a Userbox in VBA; a checkbox and a close window button.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then vb1 = -1 Else vb1 = 1


End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

UserForm1.Hide


End Sub
```

And I have this in my Module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetRangeData_inputbox()
Dim vb1, vb2, vb3, vb4, vb5, vb6, vb7 As Integer
Range("c3") = vb1 * 1000
```

The primary purpose of the userbox is to check a box. I opted for a userbox since there are many of these boxes to be checked, but I only put one in for simplistic purposes.

The Goal of this is for a box to be checked, change vb1 to -1, or vb1 to 1 if the box is checked or unchecked, then, in the module, flow into a formula that does 1,000 (for example)*VB1.

Let me know,

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is a "userbox"?  Do you mean userform?

Answer (score 0):

To use a variable in a sub you must declare it like this `Sub GetRangeData_inputbox(vb1 As Integer)` and then you must call the sub in the `CheckBox1_Click()` event.

Here is a proof of concept:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim vb1 As Integer

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then vb1 = -1 Else vb1 = 1

Call GetRangeData_inputbox(vb1)
End Sub
```

And in the module:

```
Sub GetRangeData_inputbox(vb1 As Integer)
Range("c3") = vb1 * 1000
End Sub
```

Also you can replace `UserForm1.Hide` with `UserForm1.Unload`, unless you have a reason for hiding it.